# MongoDB merge items by field name

Tags: mongodb

I Want to merge some documents array fields into one based on their field name like this

```
{
  fieldA: [ 'Ingeniero' ],
  fieldB: [ 'Biologo', 'Ingeniero' ]
}
{
  fieldA: [ 'Economista', 'Administrador Público' ],
  fieldB: [ 'Abogada' ]
}
```

Into this

```
{
  fieldA: [ 'Ingeniero', 'Economista', 'Administrador Público' ],
  fieldB: [ 'Biologo', 'Ingeniero', 'Abogada' ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$group` - Group by `null`. Create `fieldA` and `fieldB` arrays field with `$push` `fieldA` and `fieldB` arrays respectively. This results both fields are with nested arrays value.
2. `$project` - Decorate output document. For `fieldA`, with `$reduce` to transform array by `$concatArrays` for each array in `fieldA`. Same goes to `fieldB`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      fieldA: {
        $push: "$fieldA"
      },
      fieldB: {
        $push: "$fieldB"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      fieldA: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$fieldA",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      fieldB: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$fieldB",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mU2UMEk7Q-j)